# XSLT stylesheet how to perform (a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd

Tags: xslt, boolean, expression

I have an XML structure with boolean logic as below. I want to generate all the different possibilities and basically develop the expression

```
(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd
```

If the solution works for more levels ie. (e + f) or more conditions ie (a + b + c) that's even better. I've tried a couple of things without success.

```
 <Indicator operator="AND">
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>a</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>b</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>c</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>d</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>e</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>f</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
 </Indicator>
```

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. I suggest you add some values to the items and show us the expected result.

Comment: Do you expect the expression to be returned, or the expression to be evaluated? The given XML seems to have no relation with the question. You say you tried a couple of things, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to enumerate all combinations of an OR expression. Given your example, with values added for clarity:

**XML**

```
<Indicator operator="AND">
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>a</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>b</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>c</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>d</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>e</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>f</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
 </Indicator>
```

the folowing stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Indicator[@operator='AND']">
    <combinations>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Indicator[@operator='OR'][1]"/>
    </combinations>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Indicator[@operator='OR']">
    <xsl:param name="prev"/>
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::Indicator[@operator='OR']" />
    <xsl:for-each select="IndicatorItem">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="concat($prev, .)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$next">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$next[1]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="concat($this, ' AND ')"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <combination>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$this"/>
                </combination>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<combinations>
   <combination>a AND c AND e</combination>
   <combination>a AND c AND f</combination>
   <combination>a AND d AND e</combination>
   <combination>a AND d AND f</combination>
   <combination>b AND c AND e</combination>
   <combination>b AND c AND f</combination>
   <combination>b AND d AND e</combination>
   <combination>b AND d AND f</combination>
</combinations>
```

This will work for any number of OR operators and any number of OR'ed items. However, it will **not** consider any AND operators that are siblings of the OR operators being processed.

Comment: I would never have guessed that from the description, but a nice solution nevertheless :)

Comment: Sorry for geing unclear in my mesage description but you got it right! This is very elegant and works great, impressive @michael.hor257k, much appreciated. How about adding extra AND conditions that would need to be concatenated to all the combinations?
`<Indicator operator="AND">
    <IndicatorItem>x</IndicatorItem>
    <IndicatorItem>y</IndicatorItem>
    <Indicator operator="OR">
      <IndicatorItem>a</IndicatorItem>
      <IndicatorItem>b</IndicatorItem>
    </Indicator>
    ...`

Should generate something like 
`x AND y AND a AND c AND e`
`x AND y AND a AND c AND f`

Comment: @spirit You have the basic idea - how about doing the actual work yourself? -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. If you have a significantly different problem, post it as a new question (and close this one).