# Need to split and distribute xslt nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation

Need to transform XML structure mentioned below using XSLT 2.0 or 3.0,

from

```
<RD>
    <RE>
        <BI>B00</BI>
        <BI>B01</BI>
        <BI>B02</BI>
        <BI>B03</BI>
        <CI>C01</CI>
        <D>D01</D>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B04</BI>
        <BI>B05</BI>
        <CI>C02</CI>
        <D>D02</D>
    </RE>
</RD>
```

to this:

```
<RD>
    <RE>
        <BI>B00</BI>
        <CI>C01</CI>
        <D>D01</D>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B01</BI>
        <CI>C01</CI>
        <D>D01</DI>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B02</BI>
        <CI>C01</CI>
        <D>D01</D>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B03</BI>
        <CI>C01</CI>
        <D>D01</D>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B04</BI>
        <CI>C02</CI>
        <D>D02</D>
    </RE>
    <RE>
        <BI>B05</BI>
        <CI>C02</CI>
        <D>D02</D>
    </RE>
</RD>
```

Explanation:
I need to achieve the distribution of XML nodes of (CI),(D) to each of (BI) tags in every iteration of (RE) tag

Comment: I see no (L), (T), (SN) or (r) in your example. And your output has `<BI>S03</BI>` which is not present in the input.

Comment: the errors in the post are corrected. Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496962/3016153

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could also have been solved simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="RD">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="RE/BI"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BI">
    <RE>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::CI"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::D"/>
    </RE>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVK6D4y

Comment: Or even more simply: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVK6D4y/1

Comment: Shorter, but not simple to understand for an inexperienced XSLT user!

Comment: An inexperienced XSLT user can add comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it as a grouping problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="RD">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="RE" group-by="BI">
        <xsl:copy>
          <BI>{current-grouping-key()}</BI>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::BI)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ir would never have occurred to me to assume that there will be only one `CI` and only one `D`. This of course makes the problem entirely trivial. You don't even need to use grouping here - just add the two siblings to each `BI`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="RE">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BI">
        <RE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[not(self::BI)]"/>
        </RE>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```